# How can I add a proper thymeleaf source to my audio file?

Tags: java, html, spring, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I have problem putting audio in my project.
I think that there is a source problem with thymeleaf src.

```
<audio id = "player" src = "../../sound/music1.mp3" th:src="@{/sound/music1.mp3}"></audio>
        <a onclick = "document.getElementById('player').play()">
            <img th:src="@{/img/ic_play_arrow.png}"></a>
        <a onclick = "document.getElementById('player').pause()">
            <img th:src="@{/img/ic_pause.png}"></a>
        <a onclick = "document.getElementById('player').volume += 0.1">
            <img th:src="@{/img/ic_volume_up.png}"></a>
        <a onclick = "document.getElementById('player').volume -= 0.1">
            <img th:src="@{/img/ic_volume_down.png}"></a>
```

The code above belongs to a fragment based.
It is put to views like this:

```
<div th:insert="fragments/nav :: header"></div>
```

My files structure looks like this:

[image]

Pictures work fine.
Audio works when file opened by browser in Intellij.

Comment: `Audio works when file opened by browser in Intellij.` what do you mean by this? Also show us the HTML generated on the browser around the `<audio ..`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it
in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See:
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It looks like `music1.mp3` is directly in the `static` directory, not in `static/sound`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!
It was Spring security blocking the /sound folder. 
After adding:

```
                .antMatchers("/sound/**").permitAll()
```

the music plays.